# Масштабирование  всех деталий документа на n%

Tags: photoshop, adobe

Дали макет, который в ширину `5000px`, там одна кнопка только `600px`. Конечно же, придётся меньше делать. Но если каждый раз уменьшать, то надоест. Можно ли сразу уменьшить все объекты в определённое кол-во раз? Макет `psd`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выделяешь все слои в проекте, зажимаешь Ctrl+T и уменьшаешь.
Для точности можешь создать новый документ нужных размеров, потом перенести туда все слои, и только потом уменьшить. Так ты сможешь наглядно подогнать их под нужный размер.